# Limit MySQL REPEAT

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query in MySQL

```
  REPEAT
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tableB
      SELECT a.column_name, a.level+1
      FROM tableA AS a
  UNTIL Row_Count() = 0 END REPEAT;
```

but I want to put a limit on it so that it stops repeating if a.level gets above 10 (or is Row_Count() = 0).  How would I do this?

Comment: @Emmerman I've changed the wording and removed recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  REPEAT
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tableB
      SELECT a.column_name, a.level+1
      FROM tableA AS a
      WHERE a.level <= 10
  UNTIL Row_Count() = 0 END REPEAT;
```

Or i don't get it.